# Makefile comment header in the first line

Tags: vim, emacs, makefile

My question is very short I have seen in many makefiles this note:

```
# -*- MakeFile -*-
```

I wonder what is it for, is it some vim setting? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That looks like a setting for the *Emacs* editor, cp. [Choosing Modes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html#Choosing-Modes).

Vim has an equivalent called *modelines*, see `:help modeline`. It would look like this:

```
# vim:ft=make:
```

Answer (score 3):

Speaking of Vim, you may find this modeline helpful for makefiles

```
# vim: noexpandtab filetype=make
```

In most cases, Vim should already detect the filetype for a makefile. You can tell if it already finds the filetype via:

```
:set filetype?
```

and if it echos 'make' then you're good to go, else you may need the filetype specification in the modeline. I recommend the `noexpandtab` part within the modeline because tabs are relevant in a makefile and many people setup their vim to automatically expand tabs which may end up breaking a makefile etc.

Emacs has its own variant of modelines, unsure if they work tab magic and other settings but if you see them you will know what they mean now.

Comment: If you have `:filetype plugin on`, the default `ftplugin/make.vim` already sets `'noexpandtab'`.

Comment: Setting the mode line within the file becomes useful if your make file is named something like "Makefile.incl".  I have very long make files with many [phony] recipes so this becomes very useful.